# HDMI switcher causes screen to blink at 1440p on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, video, display, multiple-monitors

I use an HDMI switcher to easily switch my main monitor between my laptop and my desktop. It's a really simple standalone switcher with three HDMI inputs, one HDMI output, and an optional micro USB port for power.

When the switcher is switched to my laptop (running Linux, specifically Fedora 22), it handles 1440p resolution without issue. However, when it's switched to my desktop (running Windows 7) at 1440p, the monitor will frequently go blank for several seconds at a time (the monitor itself cuts out, not the signal). The desktop has no issues at 1080p, but naturally I'd really like to use my monitor's native resolution.

I noticed that the blanking is pretty much the same with no micro USB power or with an 0.2amp micro USB power source, but with an 0.5amp micro USB power source, it seems like the monitor cuts out quicker (but it's inconsistent, so hard to say).

I've tried setting Windows to use 59Hz or 60Hz, both with no luck (my laptop is using 59.95Hz as the framerate for the monitor).

Does anyone have any idea how I might resolve this? Is there something that could potentially be wrong with my setup on Windows?

Sanity check:

- I am indeed sure the monitor's native resolution is 1440p.
- There are no issues if the desktop is directly connected to the monitor (i.e. without the switch in between).
- The issue occurs with multiple HDMI cables.

Comment: This is pretty much expected behaviour, Wouldn't the same thing occur if you manually switched the cables, as opposed to using a switch box?

Comment: @Psycogeek Sorry, perhaps my explanation wasn't clear. The signal doesn't just cut out while it's switching; it cuts off again and again every couple of seconds as long as I'm switched to my desktop.

Comment: Ok now that is very clear.  continually, never stops blinking, stays messed up ever after :-)  Got it.

Comment: Digital is usually an all or nothing thing. either it works or it doesnt at all, something has to be right on the edge of fail to glitch like that.  the HDMI out of a computer is fully uncompressed blaze of data. If the wires total were to long for the wire quality, or the box was electronic switching type and not built well, it could cause that.  One shorter good quality cable to the switch box would  change any cable lenght issues a lot.  A cheap manually switching  video switch box, could be more simple and raw direct.

Comment: The other possibility that causes it to blip out of operation at regular or random intervals, is if the cable itself (and box) had an outside interferance occuring. (and it is close to failing)   A cell phone wi-fi signal, or even a very very close to the cable wireless input device or bluetooth.  That is where ferrite beads on the cable might add a bit of help in reducing outside interferance.

Comment: Hmm, my cable is rather close to a wireless access point, but given that the issues don't occur with the laptop and don't occur when I connect the desktop to the monitor directly (no switch in-between), I'm less inclined to suspect that as the issue.... One thing worth noting -- when the video cuts out, it isn't just the signal that cuts out; the entire monitor seems to shut off for a moment. If I'm messing with the menus using the buttons on the monitor itself, the menu goes away too when it cuts out.

Comment: Which sounds like a monitors power problem, but it is assumed you testded that with just a single cable direct in your sanity check.  There is a possibility for a power or ground problem causing tiny flows of power between 2 devices.  Sometimes plugging everything into the same area can fix that (power strip), or checking how the wiring works at each plug in point with a simple plug in tester.  but that should not be intermittant. Even a poorly isolated switching power supply.